# Plotting the student-t probability density [r]

Tags: r, distributions, data-visualization, density-function

I think it's a simple question with a simple answer but I can't find out how to do so anywhere.

I want to plot 4 different plots. v=1, v=5, v=10, v=30

I also want them to look presentable too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
curve(dt(x, 30), from = -5, to = 5, col = "orange", 
      xlab = "quantile", ylab = "density", lwd = 2)
curve(dt(x, 10), from = -5, to = 5, col = "dark green", add = TRUE, lwd = 2)
curve(dt(x, 5), from = -5, to = 5, col = "sky blue", add = TRUE, lwd = 2)
curve(dt(x, 1), from = -5, to = 5, col = "grey40", add = TRUE, lwd = 2)
legend("topleft", legend = paste0("DF = ", c(1, 5, 10, 30)),
       col = c("grey40", "sky blue", "dark green", "orange"),
       lty = 1, lwd = 2)
```

[image: plot with density curves of the t-distribution for different degrees of freedom]